# Mongoose / typegoose get array based on start and end index

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, mongodb-query, typegoose

Is there a way to get an array slice at the mongo db level? I am trying to do something similar to the following: Model.find({filter: option}, startindex, endindex). Currently the only option I found is to do the following:

```
let result = await Model.find({filter: option});
returh result.slice(startIndex, endIndex)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work since I have to pull the full record each time. If I can do this at the mongo level that would be great. Thank you for your help!

UPDATE:
After further research I found a possible solution:

```
Model.find({filter: option}).skip(skip).limit(limit);
```

it seems with this method I am able to do slice the document array in the mongo db. If you have any other ideas please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

from what i know, there isnt a way to get an slice of an array from an document, but there is the [`select`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select)

PS: `skip` skips the first documents found by the query, and `limit` limits the amount returned by the query

Comment: thank you for your response. Please correct me if I am wrong, select would allow me to specifically tell mongo to give me object a with specific fields? Also, skip and limit sort of does the same a slice would do? i was thinking if i say skip 2 that means i am at position 2 of the collection similar to me saying start at collection[2], and if I say limit 10 is similar to saying end at collection[12]?

Comment: @paul590 yes, only that it acts on the *filter* rather than the whole *collection*